# JPQL: Warning: HHH000183, Join query between two entities in different folders

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

What is the correct way to create Join query between two entities in different folder without using eg. @OneToOne relation ?

I have two entities

**First in entity/folder1**

```
package com.test.test.test.model.entity.folder1;

@Entity
@Table(name = "table1")
public class Table1 {
    @Column(name = "code", length = 6, updatable = false)
    private String code;
}
```

**And second entity in entity/folder2**

```
package com.test.test.test.model.entity.folder2;

@Entity
@Table(name = "table2")
public class Table2 {
    @Column(name = "code", length = 6, updatable = false)
    private String code;
    @Column(name = "postCode", length = 6, updatable = false)
    private String postCode;
}
```

**Query in Repository (Query working but return empty response):**

```
    @Query("""
       SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1
       JOIN com.test.test.test.model.entity.folder2.Table2 t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
       WHERE t2.postCode <> ''
    """)
    Optional<Customer> test1Query();
```

**Warning:**

```
HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1
JOIN com.test.test.test.model.entity.folder2.Table2 t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
WHERE t2.postCode <> ''
```

I spent a lot of time to fix this but i dont know how.

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried : `SELECT t1 FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.code = t2.code WHERE t2.postCode <> ''` ?

Comment: @grigouille i tried this and its show me "invalid Path name in query", so i added full package name but not working too

Comment: Are you using "exclude-unlisted-classes" ?

Comment: @grigouille, i dont using  "exclude-unlisted-classes",
 i have two data source one is mysql second is sqlserver, i have two folder one folder1 and second folder 2, i want to create join query between two table

Comment: I'm afraid you can't join entities from two different persistent units

Answer (score 0):

Because this repository interface only Customer table use.

For without using eg. @OneToOne relation, you can try use: [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html) or  [Criteria API](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries)

Comment: could you show me an example, ?i'm a beginner

Comment: There are examples in link.

Comment: Criteria API not working without eg. @OneToOne, entity manager too